# I need to organize the rows in the proper order with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to organize my data with pandas. Currently, this is what my json file looks like:

```
    "Instagram": {
      "2021-06-15": 2.0
    },
    "Twitter": {
      "2021-06-16": 4.0,
      "2021-06-15": 4.0,
      "2021-06-14": 6.0,
      "2021-06-13": 9.0,
      "2021-06-12": 4.0,
      "2021-06-11": 7.0,
      "2021-06-10": 9.0
    },
```

When I have pandas read the json file and convert to pandas and print(pd.DataFrame()). It outputs like this:

```
                 Instagram       Twitter
   2021-06-15       2.0            4.0
   2021-06-16       NaN            4.0
   2021-06-14       NaN            6.0
   2021-06-13       NaN            9.0
   2021-06-12       NaN            4.0
   2021-06-11       NaN            7.0
   2021-06-10       NaN            9.0
```

You'll see that the dates aren't in the correct order in the rows. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Because I need the dates to be in the exact order.

Comment: `df.sort_index` ?

Comment: @Nk03 I currently have this in my python code: 
data = pd.read_json('name_of_file.json')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

this is giving the results above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [DataFrame.sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) method, you can sort the index (which are the dates in your case) to be in the correct order.

You might want to use the keyword argument `ascending=False` so it sorts with the most recent dates at the top

e.g. `df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)`
or `df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)`

Comment: this seems to have worked but now i'm getting NaN for both twitter and instagram on 6-15-2021 :/

Comment: Strange, I just ran this in jupyter notebook and it worked fine for me here is a link to a [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/c2665eb959565ab7d5fcaa8d55490d16)

Comment: OH whoops. I forgot to mention that after i implemented that, i did df.pct_change() which is why it's showing NaN for both instagram and twitter on 6-15

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense now, if you would like you could add the keyword `fill_method='ffill'` to your df.pct_change() to deal with NaNs (better explained with example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) on the docs)

Answer (score 0):

The index will be in datetime format, so you can sort that

```
import pandas as pd

d={   "Instagram": {
      "2021-06-15": 2.0
    },
    "Twitter": {
      "2021-06-16": 4.0,
      "2021-06-15": 4.0,
      "2021-06-14": 6.0,
      "2021-06-13": 9.0,
      "2021-06-12": 4.0,
      "2021-06-11": 7.0,
      "2021-06-10": 9.0
    },}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.sort_index()
print(df)
```

Comment: this seems to have worked but now i'm getting NaN for both twitter and instagram on 6-15-2021 :/

Comment: Made an  edit, assigned the dataframe with updated one, try this

Comment: I forgot to mention that after i implemented that, i did df.pct_change() which is why it's showing NaN for both instagram and twitter on 6-15-2021